# Cannot join output of all Pool processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I cannot collect output of all Pool processes. Resulted dictionary probably contains output of 1 of 3 parallel processes (288 of 411 elements).
Here is my code.

```
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def reader(entry, outcomes): #other args are constant
   .............................................
   #Some condition:
   prediction = min(distances) + (mlc_data[min(distances)[1]],)
   outcomes[entry_pairs[' '.join(entry)]] = prediction
   return outcomes

manager = Manager()
outcomes = manager.dict()
with Pool(3) as p:
  output = p.starmap(reader, zip(input[0], repeat(outcomes)))
  p.close()
  p.join()
```

Finally, I have only 288 of 411 elements in outcomes dictionary.
From the other side, i have 411**2 elements in output, that probably means, that my code is not well optimized.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need close and join when using a `with` clause. That is done for you.

Comment: If `entry_pairs[' '.join(entry)]` isn't unique in each call to reader, then some predictions will overwrite other predictions in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the entire, ever-growing `outcomes` dictionary with each call to reader. That is serialized, sent to the parent process, deserialized and then added to `output`. That is a huge cost, especially considering that the manager is also moving the data between processes to keep the dict in sync. `reader` could return `prediction` and its key instead. Then let the parent process build the result dictionary. This also lets you test all of the returned keys to make sure there are no duplicates.

```
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool

def reader(entry): #other args are constant
    #Some condition:
    prediction = min_d:=min(distances) + (mlc_data[min_d[1]],)
    return entry_pairs[' '.join(entry)], prediction

outcomes = {}
with Pool(3) as p:
    for key, prediction in p.starmap(reader, zip(input[0], repeat(outcomes))):
        if key in outcomes:
            print("ERROR, key duplicated:", key)
        else:
            outcomes[key] = prediction
```

Comment: @tedelaney: your approach seems to be much faster, but processes are not synchronized without Manager.  I got UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prediction' referenced before assignment.

Comment: I didn't see any reason why the processes should be synchronized in the given code. That synchronization can be expensive and is best avoided when possible.

Comment: As for unbound..., its not a problem in the example I posted, so it must be something in the full implementation you have. See if you have a code path that skips the assignment to the variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I`v found two cases without assignment. Now your code working well.

Answer (score 0):

Update `reader` function with a the shared dictionary `outcomes` and use `Pool`

```
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def reader(entry, outcomes):  # other args are constant
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    prediction = min(distances) + (mlc_data[min(distances)[1]],)
    outcomes[entry_pairs[' '.join(entry)]] = prediction

manager = Manager()
outcomes = manager.dict()

with Pool(3) as p:
    p.starmap(reader, zip(input[0], repeat(outcomes)))

print(len(outcomes))
```

Comment: No changes, resulted outcomes dict contains 288 elements.